# Prometheus dashboard exposed over ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, prometheus-operator

I am trying to setup Prometheus in k8 cluster, able to run using helm. Accessing dashboard when i expose prometheus-server as LoadBalancer service using external ip.
Same does not work when I try to configure this service as ClusterIP and making it as backend using ingress controller. Receiving 404 error, any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ops-ingress
  annotations:
    #nginx.org/server-snippet: "proxy_ssl_verify off;"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-server
          servicePort: 80
```

with above ingress definition in place, url  “http://<>/prometheus/ getting redirected to http://<>/graph/ and then 404 error page getting rendered. When url adjusted to http://<>/prometheus/graph some of webcontrols gets rendered with lots of errors on browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus might be expecting to have control over the root path (/).

Please change the Ingress to `prometheus.example.com` and it should work fine. (Changing it to a subdomain)

Comment: Do you mean adding host as prometheus.example.com? Added host and receiving same 404 error, later url adjusted to `http://prometheus.example.com/prometheus/graph` and some of webcontrols gets rendered with lots of errors on browser console.So basically the behavior is the same as it was.

Comment: remove the path field too, so ideally your url will become `prometheus.example.com/graph`

Comment: If path is removed and off-course making rewrite to root (/), web console for prometheus works. But with this how to manage multiple services with one ingress controller exposed on one IP? My thought was to have different paths defined for different services (fanout routing)

Comment: you can configure your dns of `*.example.com` to the same IP and you can do subdomain based routing. so you can get `service1.example.com` and `service2.example.com` this is standard practice. As you mentioned my answer solves your problem, please do accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Please change your Ingress configuration file, add `host` field:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ops-ingress
  annotations:
    #nginx.org/server-snippet: "proxy_ssl_verify off;"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: prometheus.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-server
          servicePort: 80
```

then apply changes executing command:

```
$ kubectl aply -f your_ingress_congifguration_file.yaml
```

The `host` header field in a request provides the host and port
information from the target URI, enabling the origin server to
distinguish among resources while servicing requests for multiple
host names on a single IP address.

Please take a look here: [hosts-header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4).

Ingress definition: [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Useful information: [helm-prometheus](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress).

Useful documentation: [ingress-path-matching](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/351ce5394a5ec37153344135c8112f71539b5af4/docs/user-guide/ingress-path-matching.md#ingress-path-matching).

Comment: Tried adding host and behavior remains the same. Upon looking further this the error in ingress controller log `xx.xxx.xxx.xx - - [17/Jan/2020:19:49:56 +0000] "GET /static/css/graph.css?v=6f92ce56053866194ae5937012c1bec40f1dd1d9 HTTP/1.1" 404 190 "http://prometheus.example.com/prometheus/graph" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36" 428 0.000 [upstream-default-backend] [] `